# How do I use Microduino (mCookie) on Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm interested in getting the [mCookie](https://wiki.microduino.cc/index.php/MCookie_Series) working in Linux — specifically, in Fedora 23. The Arduino IDE (version 1.6.4) is already available. I'm very familiar with Linux, fine with C, and completely new to Arduino.

The tutorials for [Windows](https://wiki.microduino.cc/index.php/Getting_started:_Windows) or [Mac](https://wiki.microduino.cc/index.php/Getting_started:_Mac) describe installing a customized version of the IDE along with drivers. Do I *need* special drivers on Linux? On the projects' GitHub site, I found [the examples](https://github.com/wasdpkj/Microduino-IDE-Support/tree/master/arduino-ide-Support/[1.6.x]-hardware%28library%29/examples/00.mCookie) and [a directory called 'avr'](https://github.com/wasdpkj/Microduino-IDE-Support/tree/master/arduino-ide-Support/[1.6.x]-hardware%28library%29/hardware/Microduino/avr) which has promising subdirectories like "bootloaders" and "libraries", along with files `boards.txt` and `platform.txt`.

Can I download this stuff and add it to the existing "system" arduino package somehow? How, and what will I need?

Comment: I'd tag this [tag:mcookie] and/or [tag:microduino] if I could....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need the `arduino` 1.6.x package from `updates`, not the 1.0.x package from `fedora`. Then:

> You will be adding a URL to the new Additional Boards Manager URLs option: https://github.com/wasdpkj/Microduino-IDE-Support/raw/master/package_Microduino_index.json

[source](https://github.com/wasdpkj/Microduino-IDE-Support)

[This tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/add-boards-arduino-v164/overview) tells you where and how to add that URL to the preferences, as well as how to actually install the required support files.

---

As of this writing, the platform configuration supplied as part of the above won't work out of the box in Linux; you will also have to edit `~/.arduino15/packages/Microduino/hardware/avr/1.6.7/platform.txt` to:

- replace `compiler.path={runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path}/bin/` with just `compiler.path=/usr/bin/`
- on the line starting `recipe.ar.pattern=`, change `{archive_file_path}` to `{build.path}/{archive_file}`

Hopefully this will be fixed in future versions.

---

You probably also want to prevent ModemManager from probing the serial device with this udev rule, just replace the vendor and product IDs as appropriate:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb-serial", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="xxxx", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! This resulted in an error: `Could not find boards.txt in /home/mattdm/.arduino15/packages/Microduino/hardware/avr/1.6.7. Is it pre-1.5?` and exit on startup. However, when looking at that directory, there's an `avr` subdirectory with `boards.txt` in; I moved everything up one level and now it seems to be working....

Comment: @mattdm: That would seem to be a problem with their files; I also see all `boards.txt` files (on my system) directly in the architecture-appropriate directories rather than in any subdirectories.

Comment: I guess I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Ugh, that also hardcodes `compiler.path={runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path}/bin/` in `./packages/Microduino/hardware/avr/1.6.7/platform.txt`, when it should be (I think) just `compiler.path=/usr/bin/` ... fixed that, and now I've got an error about `{archive_file_path}`. I've got some further research to do here, I see.

Comment: So, from [here](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino/issues/315), that should be replaced with `{build.path}/{archive_file}`. Now a really simple sketch compiles but does not seem to actually upload. That's the next step, I guess. :)

Comment: Whoo. Final step was "bad USB cable replaced". :)